# Net Unrealized Appreciation (NUA) on Rollover scenario

Tags: united-states, ira, rollover

Finding [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6904/should-i-cash-out-or-rollover-401k-securities?newreg=7f008d32ed1f4faf8bdcac120e0651fd) as maybe the closest match, to the scenario, I also find that [this](https://www.kitces.com/blog/net-unrealized-appreciation-irs-rules-nua-from-401k-and-esop-plans/) and [this](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/netunrealizedappreciation.asp) strongly suggest that NUA rules only apply to Employer stock purchases.  In other words, if I work for Acme, then only Acme stock is in question here.  So, in a portfolio with many options, only a portion of the whole may (in my understanding) have NUA rules applied; all other sources would follow those rules.

That said, everything I'm finding talks of distributions, not specifically Rollovers to another IRA.  The rules and advise say that NUA rules are a tradeoff (taxes will be paid somewhere).

My question is simple, if I roll a portfolio, considering that means selling (realizing) the gain, is that the same as a "distribution" in terms of tax liability?

Thanks in advance.